# SQL Join two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

Right now I have a table that may or may not have data for a specific day.  However, I would like to return a dataset with all dates and blank data filled in for the other columns.  I figured another table with "all dates" stored in it and a view would help me accomplish this.  If there is a better way please let me know.

**table1**

```
UserId    Date       Value1
1         9/2/2012   10
2         9/15/2012  5
1         9/17/2012  12
1         9/23/2012  4
2         9/25/2012  7
```

**AllDates** (has a record of every date for the next 10 years)

```
Date
1/1/2012
1/2/2012
1/3/2012
...
...
...
12/31/2020
```

I would like to join the two tables to return this dataset for the month of September where UserId = 1:

```
UserId    Date       Value1
1         9/1/2012   NULL
1         9/2/2012   10
1         9/3/2012   NULL
...
...
...
1         9/16/2012   NULL
1         9/17/2012   12
1         9/18/2012   NULL
...
...
...
1         9/23/2012  4
...
...
...
1         9/29/2012  NULL
1         9/30/2012  NULL
```

Comment: Do you have a table with all user-IDs in it?

Comment: Before you try to offer your opinion, you should go back and look at my previous questions.  There were no acceptable answers to mark as the "correct" answer.  In cases where there were, I have marked them.  Got to love the SO police.

Comment: If it's really true that so few of your questions result in acceptable answers, then that most likely indicates a problem with your questions. ;-)

Comment: Or I think so far outside the box and above the intellectual capacity of everyone on SO. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a.Date, t.Value1
from AllDates a
left outer join table1 t on a.Date = t.Date and t.UserID = 1
where year(a.Date) = 2012 and month(a.Date) = 9    
order by a.Date
```

Comment: Works great, will accept the answer in 1 minute...telling me I can't just yet.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you convert this to linq?  I could not place this code in a View because I need to pass in the variable of UserId.  I can just execute this directly from linq, but having a hard time converting it. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianSalta That is best asked as a separate question.

Comment: I did ask as a new question, can you get to it through my profile? Thanks.